# How can I pass a parameter to a Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

While developing a website, I've encountered this problem:

I've a list of panels movies, created using a for loop, and each one of them has a "Delete" button. Each delete button has an unique id (movie id in my database).

I need to send that id to the backend, developed in Django, using AJAX.
How can I achieve this?

Here is my HTML code for creating the movie panel list:

```html
<ul>
        {% if film_list %}
        {% for film in film_list %}
                <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-xl-3 name">
                                        <img width="50" height="50" src= {{ film.poster }} alt= {{ film.title }}>
                                        <strong> {{ film.title }} </strong>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-xl-9">
                                        <div class= "col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-xl-4">
                                                <button id = "{{ film.id }}" class="btn boton-delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal-delete">
                                                        <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete"></span>
                                                        Borrar película
                                                </button>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
</ul>
```

And here is the HTML code of the modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade modal-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">¿Está seguro de que quiere borrar esta película?</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success modal-btn-si">Si</button>
                        <button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger modal-btn-no">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viendo que eres español me adapto a tu idioma.

Al botón que abre el modal, yo le quitaba la apertura mediante propiedades para gestionarlo desde jquery:

```
<button id = "{{ film.id }}" class="btn boton-delete"<span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete"></span>Borrar película</button>
```

Para iniciar el borrado tienes que hacerlo con javascript/jquery, es decir:

```
<script>
    var id;
    $(".boton-delete").on('click', function(e){
        $("#id_modal").modal();
        id = this.id;
    });

    $("#id_boton_confirmacion").click(function(e){
        $("#id_modal").modal('hide');
        // Realizar llamada AJAX pasandole la variable id
    });
</script>
```

Respecto a los botones del modal tienes que quitarle la propiedad `submit` pues no hay formulario, sería:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success modal-btn-si">Si</button>
<button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger modal-btn-no">No</button>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, aun soy un poco novato en esto. Funciona a la perfección, gracias!